# GEE python export process often interrupt

Tags: google-earth-engine

I'm using python to download many data from Google earth engine iteratively, the function I use is like this:

```
for i in range():
    task=ee.batch.Export.table.toDrive()
    task.start()
```

But I find that the download process often interrupt, the output is like as follow:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/wxystudio/miniconda3/envs/wxy/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 703, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "/Users/wxystudio/miniconda3/envs/wxy/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 386, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/Users/wxystudio/miniconda3/envs/wxy/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 1042, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/Users/wxystudio/miniconda3/envs/wxy/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 419, in connect
    self.sock = ssl_wrap_socket(
  File "/Users/wxystudio/miniconda3/envs/wxy/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 449, in ssl_wrap_socket
    ssl_sock = _ssl_wrap_socket_impl(
  File "/Users/wxystudio/miniconda3/envs/wxy/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 493, in _ssl_wrap_socket_impl
    return ssl_context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "/Users/wxystudio/miniconda3/envs/wxy/lib/python3.10/ssl.py", line 513, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
  File "/Users/wxystudio/miniconda3/envs/wxy/lib/python3.10/ssl.py", line 1071, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/Users/wxystudio/miniconda3/envs/wxy/lib/python3.10/ssl.py", line 1342, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 54] Connection reset by peer

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/wxystudio/miniconda3/envs/wxy/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 489, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "/Users/wxystudio/miniconda3/envs/wxy/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 787, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "/Users/wxystudio/miniconda3/envs/wxy/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 550, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "/Users/wxystudio/miniconda3/envs/wxy/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 769, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/Users/wxystudio/miniconda3/envs/wxy/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 703, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "/Users/wxystudio/miniconda3/envs/wxy/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 386, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/Users/wxystudio/miniconda3/envs/wxy/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 1042, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/Users/wxystudio/miniconda3/envs/wxy/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 419, in connect
    self.sock = ssl_wrap_socket(
  File "/Users/wxystudio/miniconda3/envs/wxy/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 449, in ssl_wrap_socket
    ssl_sock = _ssl_wrap_socket_impl(
  File "/Users/wxystudio/miniconda3/envs/wxy/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 493, in _ssl_wrap_socket_impl
    return ssl_context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "/Users/wxystudio/miniconda3/envs/wxy/lib/python3.10/ssl.py", line 513, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
  File "/Users/wxystudio/miniconda3/envs/wxy/lib/python3.10/ssl.py", line 1071, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/Users/wxystudio/miniconda3/envs/wxy/lib/python3.10/ssl.py", line 1342, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(54, 'Connection reset by peer'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/wxystudio/Desktop/research/NIFA Yield Prediction Project/wxy/code/getpixel05.py", line 355, in <module>
    task.start()
  File "/Users/wxystudio/miniconda3/envs/wxy/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ee/batch.py", line 94, in start
    result = data.exportTable(self._request_id, self.config)
  File "/Users/wxystudio/miniconda3/envs/wxy/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ee/data.py", line 1524, in exportTable
    return _prepare_and_run_export(
  File "/Users/wxystudio/miniconda3/envs/wxy/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ee/data.py", line 1612, in _prepare_and_run_export
    return _execute_cloud_call(
  File "/Users/wxystudio/miniconda3/envs/wxy/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ee/data.py", line 337, in _execute_cloud_call
    return call.execute(num_retries=num_retries)
  File "/Users/wxystudio/miniconda3/envs/wxy/lib/python3.10/site-packages/googleapiclient/_helpers.py", line 130, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/wxystudio/miniconda3/envs/wxy/lib/python3.10/site-packages/googleapiclient/http.py", line 923, in execute
    resp, content = _retry_request(
  File "/Users/wxystudio/miniconda3/envs/wxy/lib/python3.10/site-packages/googleapiclient/http.py", line 191, in _retry_request
    resp, content = http.request(uri, method, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/wxystudio/miniconda3/envs/wxy/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google_auth_httplib2.py", line 218, in request
    response, content = self.http.request(
  File "/Users/wxystudio/miniconda3/envs/wxy/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ee/_cloud_api_utils.py", line 62, in request
    response = session.request(
  File "/Users/wxystudio/miniconda3/envs/wxy/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 587, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/Users/wxystudio/miniconda3/envs/wxy/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 701, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/wxystudio/miniconda3/envs/wxy/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 547, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(54, 'Connection reset by peer'))
```

Of course I can re-run the code to download, but it is annoying.
So my question is, is it a common problem in GEE python? is there any method that can re-run the task when the task interrupts?

Comment: How long does it take to create each export task, and how many tasks are you starting? It seems that your python script is taking too long and eventually the connection with the ee servers is interrupted. If this is the case, then try to split your tasks and handle a batch of tasks in one call to your python script.

Comment: @OliverLopez  you'are right, there are thousands of tasks. So I can only split them to run. Thanks.